# Bootstrap 4: Align text with a icon inside a bootstrap Button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons

How could I line the text below the icon, so the text stays inside the button?

Im using that button inside a table

Image Preview:
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHiU6.png)

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "LocalDaOperacao", new {id=item.LocalDaOperacaoID})"class="btn btn-warning" id="tamanho-botoes" >
   <span class="fa fa-edit"> Edit</span>
  </a>

#tamanho-botoes {
    width: 38px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
  <a href=""class="btn btn-warning p-1" id="tamanho-botoes" >
   <span class="fa fa-edit"></span><br><span class="">Edit</span>
  </a>

#tamanho-botoes {
    width: 38px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Check out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lycrest15/aq9Laaew/306301/)

Hope this helps.